# C++ Assign char** to an array of strings

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I know that you can assign a character array to a string:

```cpp
#include <string>
using std::string;

char foo[] = "foo";
string str = foo;
```

But how do you assign an array of character arrays (char**) to an array of strings?

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, please post what you have tried and indicate where you are running into problems.

Comment: I cannot post any examples because I have no idea how to go about doing this. The code is only for the first sentence

Comment: @ryyker, yes, the standard C++ library has a `std::string` class. `string str = foo;` is a perfectly valid statement, due to the `using std::string;` statement above it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    const char * a[] = { "Hello", "World" };

    std::vector<std::string> v( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ) );

    for ( const auto &s : v ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello World
```

Or

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 2;
    const char ** a = new const char * [N] { "Hello", "World" };

    std::vector<std::string> v( a, a + N );

    for ( const auto &s : v ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    delete [] a;

    return 0;
}
```